# Checking oracle sid and database name

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to check SID and current database name.

I am using following query for checking oracle SID

```
select instance from v$thread;
```

but table or view does not exist error is coming.

I am using following query for checking current database name

```
select name from v$database;
```

but table or view does not exist error is coming.

Any idea for above two problems?

Comment: use 
SELECT INSTANCE_NAME FROM V$INSTANCE;

Answer (score 178, accepted):

I presume `SELECT user FROM dual;` should give you the current user

and `SELECT sys_context('userenv','instance_name') FROM dual;` the name of the instance

I believe you can get SID as `SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL;`

Comment: Thanks for quick response.Are instance and oracle SID same thing?

Comment: @Adnan They need not be the same since there coould be multiple instances of the DB running on a single machine they are identified by SID

Comment: @adnan Did you get the values you needed ?

Comment: No. I want to get database name instead of current user and oracle sid instead of instance.

Comment: `select sys_context('userenv','db_name') from dual;` for database name and sid i have already added in the answer. hope this gives you what you want

Comment: Thanks for your time. i have got database name but when i use select sys_context('userenv','SId') from dual i'm getting empty column,does it mean sid not set? If thats true then how can we set SID?

Comment: Please check this [link](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:1589451392620155::::P11_QUESTION_ID:318216852435)

Comment: @V4Vendetta When installing Oracle, I had to see my environment using `.bash_profile` which also contains the env var `ORACLE_SID`. If we configure it via env variables, doesn't it mean it will remain the same for every database that is created?

Comment: select sys_context('userenv','instance_name') from dual; worked for me while doing jpa definition to eclipse, thank you.

Comment: sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') is the session id which changes for every new connection, not what the OP was asking for.  

In this case SID seems to have an overloaded meaning, but what the OP needs is:  

SID = SELECT sys_context('userenv','instance_name') FROM dual;  

SERVICE_NAME = select value from v$parameter where name like '%service_name%';

Answer (score 83):

If, like me, your goal is get the database host and SID to generate a Oracle JDBC url, as

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<server_host>:1521:<instance_name>
```

the following commands will help:

Oracle query command to check the SID (or instance name):

```
select sys_context('userenv','instance_name') from dual;
```

Oracle query command to check database name (or server host):

```
select sys_context('userenv', 'server_host') from dual;
```

Att.
Sergio Marcelo

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I wanted to know, but didn't know how to phrase.

Comment: Me too. Thanks Sergio!

Answer (score 54):

Just for completeness, you can also use ORA_DATABASE_NAME.

It might be worth noting that not all of the methods give you the same output:

```
SQL> select sys_context('userenv','db_name') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','DB_NAME')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
orcl

SQL> select ora_database_name from dual;

ORA_DATABASE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORCL.XYZ.COM

SQL> select * from global_name;

GLOBAL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORCL.XYZ.COM
```

Comment: No special permissions are needed for the queries above. Verified by creating a new user with CONNECT privilege only.

Answer (score 27):

The V$ views are mainly dynamic views of system metrics.  They are used for performance tuning, session monitoring, etc.  So access is limited to DBA users by default, which is why you're getting `ORA-00942`.

The easiest way of finding the database name is:

```
select * from global_name;
```

This view is granted to PUBLIC, so anybody can query it.

Comment: Whats about oracle SID? Is there any method for checking it from scott account?

Comment: That's the service name, not the SID.

Answer (score 6):

Type on `sqlplus` command prompt

```
SQL> select * from global_name;
```

then u will be see result on command prompt

```
SQL ORCL.REGRESS.RDBMS.DEV.US.ORACLE.COM
```

Here first one "ORCL" is database name,may be your system "XE" and other what was given on oracle downloading time.

Comment: Thanks, you made my day.

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned above,

```
select global_name from global_name;
```

is the way to go.

You couldn't query v$database/v$instance/v$thread because your user does not have the required permissions. You can grant them (via a DBA account) with:

```
grant select on v$database to <username here>;
```

Answer (score 3):

***SID*** appears to be an overloaded term in the Oracle environment.
There's lots of answers on topic which say:
SID = SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL;

However please note that this shows your current session_id, and changes for every new connection to the DB.

When referring to SID and current database name in the same question one can safely assume that the OP is trying to configure connections in tnsnames or elsewhere, and not trying to identify the session_id of a currently connected session.

Therefore in this context:
SID = `SELECT sys_context('userenv','instance_name') FROM dual;`

SERVICE_NAME = `select sys_context('userenv','service_name') from dual;`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT sys_context('userenv','instance_name') FROM dual;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).