# cx_Oracle doesn't connect when using SID instead of service name on connection string

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I have a connection string that looks like this

```
con_str = "myuser/mypass@oracle.sub.example.com:1521/ora1"
```

Where `ora1` is the SID of my database. Using this information in SQL Developer works fine, meaning that I can connect and query without problems.

However, if I attempt to connect to Oracle using this string, it fails.

```
cx_Oracle.connect(con_str)

DatabaseError:  ORA-12514:  TNS:listener  does  not  currently  know  of  service  requested  in  connect  descriptor
```

This connection string format works if the `ora1` is a service name, though.

I have seen other questions that seem to have the reverse of my problem (it works with SID, but not Service name)

- [Using Oracle Service Names with SQLAlachemy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14140902/189134)
- [Oracle SID and Service name; connection problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13691628/189134)
- [cx_Oracle & Connecting to Oracle DB Remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181699/189134)

What is the proper way to connect to Oracle, using `cx_Oracle`, using an `SID` and not a service name?  How do I do this without the need to adjust the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file? My application is distributed to many users internally and making changes to the `TNSNAMES` file is less than ideal when dealing with users without administrator privileges on their Windows machines. Additionally, when I use service name, I don't need to touch this file at all and would like it keep it that way.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I a similar scenario, I was able to connect to the database by using [`cx_Oracle.makedsn()`](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/module.html) to create a **dsn** string with a given `SID` (instead of the service name):

```
dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("oracle.sub.example.com", "1521", "ora1")
```

This returns something like

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle.sub.example.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ora1)))
```

which can then be used with [`cx_Oracle.connect()`](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/module.html) to connect to the database:

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="myuser", password="mypass", dsn=dsnStr)
print con.version
con.close()
```

Comment: The documentation is very clear. Just do `cx_Oracle.makedsn("oracle.sub.example.com", "1521", service_name="ora1")`, explicitly using the keyword `service_name` to differentiate it from the third argument (which is `sid`).

Comment: Very useful, landed here after 2 days of search and it worked in less than 30 seconds. Terrific. Thanks a lot @Andreas Fester.

Comment: A mere upvote is not enough to express my gratitude.

Comment: Spent the whole day figuring out why i was not able to write to oracledb. Some issue connecting. This answer from 10 years ago is a lifesaver. Works like a charm! Thank you so much @andreas!!!

Answer (score 7):

For those looking for how to specify *service_name* instead of SID.

From [changelog](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/changelog_10.html#change-1.0.0b1) for SQLAlchemy 1.0.0b1 (released on March 13, 2015):

> [oracle] [feature] Added support for cx_oracle connections to a
>   specific service name, as opposed to a tns name, by passing
>   `?service_name=<name>` to the URL. Pull request courtesy Sławomir
>   Ehlert.

The change introduces new, Oracle dialect specific option **`service_name`** which can be used to build connect string like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import url

connect_url = url.URL(
    'oracle+cx_oracle',
    username='some_username',
    password='some_password',
    host='some_host',
    port='some_port',
    query=dict(service_name='some_oracle_service_name'))

engine = create_engine(connect_url)
```

Comment: This is question about `cx_Oracle` not `sqlalchemy`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using sqlalchemy and ORACLE 12, the following seems to work.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
con='oracle://user:password@hostname:1521/?service_name=DDDD'
engine = create_engine(con)
```

Note, you have to use the service name and not the SID. I don't know why, but the simple connection string that uses SID does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It still may not work. You need to take the output of dsnStr and modify the string by replacing SID with SERVICE_NAME and use that variable in the con string.  This procedure worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

SID's may not be easily accessible or you might not have it created for your database.

In my case, I'm working from the client side requesting access to a cloud database so creating an SID didn't really make sense.

Instead, you might have a string that looks similar to this:

```
"(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = something.cloud.company)
(PORT = 12345)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = something.cloud.company)
(PORT = 12345)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = 
something.company)))"
```

You can use it in replacement of the SID.

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("username", "pw", "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = 
                (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = something.cloud.company)(PORT = 12345)) (ADDRESS = 
                (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = something.cloud.company)(PORT = 12345)) 
                (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = something.company)))")
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought during a while that I would not be able to use Magic SQL (`%sql`, `%%sql`) because of service name issue in connection that would force to use the alternative way described above with cx_Oracle.connect(), `cx_Oracle.makedsn()...` I finally found a solution working for me: declare and set a variable for the service name first and then use it in the command (since not working if literal string for service name put in the command !)

```
import cx_Oracle

user='youruser'
pwd='youruserpwd'
dbhost='xx.xx.xx.xx'
service='yourservice'

%load_ext sql
%sql oracle+cx_oracle://$user:$pwd@$dbhost:1521/?service_name=$service
```

output (what you get in successful connection):

```
u'Connected: youruser@'
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking to set oracle.jdbc.proxyClientName property for **cx_oracle**, to connect using proxyClient, they can use -

```
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client("../../oracle_local_client", config_dir= "../../oracle_local_client/network/admin")

connectDsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('db.svr.net', 'portNumberHere',service_name="TEST_READWRITE")
#replace all prams above

pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(externalauth=True, homogeneous=False, dsn = connectDsn)
connection = pool.acquire(user="[PROXY_CLIENT_NAME]")
```

Notice the use of **'['** braces to depict that the user is **proxyClient**.
I am using Kerberos authentication for this and my SQLNET.ora file contains the below properties.

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(TNSNAMES,HOSTNAME,EZCONNECT)
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (BEQ,KERBEROS5PRE,KERBEROS5)
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS5_SERVICE=oracle
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME=OSMSFT:
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF_MIT=TRUE
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF=I:\projects\poc\resources\krb5.conf # krb5 config file complete path.
```

For more information, refer the video embedded in this [article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:551:::NO:551:P551_CLASS_ID:6213:).

Answer (score -1):

I also met this issue.
The solution is:

```
1: get the service name at tnsnames.ora
2: put the service name in
con_str = "myuser/mypass@oracle.sub.example.com:1521/ora1"
```