# cx_Oracle Am I using the host name incorrectly?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I use Toad to connect to my Oracle database and that works fine however I am trying to use cx_Oracle to connect to the same database and my program gets stuck at the `.connect()` method.

I believe the issue is the `host` name but I cant be sure as no errors exist just does not get past the `connect()` call.

```
import cx_Oracle


CONN_INFO = {'host': '\\\\SERVERNAMEUSEDINTOAD\\',
             'port': 1111,
             'user': 'USER123',
             'psw': 'password',
             'service': 'dbname.somesite.com'}
print("test1")
CONN_STR = '{user}/{psw}@{host}:{port}/{service}'.format(**CONN_INFO)
print("test2")
con = cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)
print("test3")
print(con.fetchmany([1]))
```

Console:

```
test1
test2
```

I make it to `test2` but not `test3`. Am I using the host name correctly? The host is an internal server on the network.

TOAD application displays just `SERVERNAMEUSEDINTOAD` so I tried that as well:

```
'host': 'SERVERNAMEUSEDINTOAD'
```

But this resulted in the following error:

```
test1
test2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/name/PycharmProjects/WorkFlow/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Comment: `print(CONN_STR)` instead of `test2` would be more interesting… the error given suggests that the resulting `CONN_STR` isn't what it needs (stating the obvious). The backslashes in the first CONN_INFO don't look fine to me… Is what you've took from Toad really the server host or the TNS name of `tnsnames.ora`? See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245465/cx-oracle-connecting-to-oracle-db-remotely) can help you someway — from an answer there, your second string should be fine, provided the connection data are correct.

Comment: @ShinTakezou I have tried that as well and it never prints. Like its hung up. That said I have resolved the issue by using `makedsn()` first then connect with those settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging I found this post:

[cx_Oracle doesn't connect when using SID instead of service name on connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149138/cx-oracle-doesnt-connect-when-using-sid-instead-of-service-name-on-connection-s).

Thought it was about connecting with the SID there was a post that suggested to use `makedsn()` and then use this to connect.

Turns out that solved my issue as well with connecting via the service_name.

I am posting my solution here so anyone who finds this post will have a option to fix this problem.

```
import cx_Oracle

or_dns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('SERVERNAMEUSEDINTOAD', 1111, service_name='dbname.somesite.com')

con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="USER123", password="password", dsn=or_dns)
print(con)
```

Console:

```
<cx_Oracle.Connection to USER123@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=SERVERNAMEUSEDINTOAD)(PORT=1111))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=dbname.somesite.com)))>
```

Comment: add print(or_dns) after your call to makedsn. The output is a string that looks like a tnsnames.ora entry. I wonder if this is a cx_oracle bug. This page makes you think it should work as you originally did it. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html

Comment: @BobbyDurrett I will have to check Monday as I am leaving the office.

Comment: No worries. It looks like replacing the host name with the ip address works. Have a good weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two things to get your example to work on my laptop.

I had to update my sqlnet.ora to have this line:

names.directory_path = (TNSNAMES,EZCONNECT)

instead of

names.directory_path = (TNSNAMES)

Then I had to use the ip address for my host instead of the hostname.

I do not think this is a bug in cx_oracle because sqlplus did not work either with the same syntax. But, it worked with the ip address and EZCONNECT in my sqlnet.ora.

Bobby