# Connection refused Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to connect to my oracle 11g DB with a java program and it is giving errors described below. It is fine When try to connect from SQL developer.

By using ojdbc5.jar in program, getting the below exception,

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

By using ojdbc14.jar, getting the below one,

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=186647552)(ERR=12505)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12505)(EMFI=4))))
```

Do i need to change the format of passing URL, user name and password? I have passed below string to establish connection.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:SID
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error's because you're passing the wrong value of SID.

Comment: Sure that I am passing valid service name. Checked with SQL Developer and is fine with same

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691628/oracle-sid-and-service-name-connection-problems?rq=1

Comment: Yes, the format of the connection string is different when using a SID and service name.

Comment: All the links were not resolved the issue. Getting this error only from past couple of days. A strange one!