# How to find Oracle Service Name

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle database on my network which I am able to connect to with Oracle SQL Developer, using hostname, port, username, password and the SID.

I need to connect another application (Quantum Gis), however it uses the Service Name instead of the SID.

Is there any way for me to determine the SERVICE_NAME of the database when I am connected in SQL Developer via the SID?

I do not have access to the server and have no local tnsnames.ora or similar.

Comment: Jakobsen:Just run the command `Show parameter service_name`

Comment: @GauravSoni AFAIK `show parameter` is a SQL/Plus command, and I'm not sure whether SQL Developer supports a SQL/Plus prompt. If it doesn't, the OP could use `select * from v$parameter where name like '%service_name%'` instead.

Comment: "Show parameter service_name;" returns error "Show parameters query failed".

Comment: "select value from v$parameter where name like '%service_name%';" returns ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: @AndersJakobsen:you dint have access to the data dictionary views ,ask your DBA to give access or send you the service name .And may be sql developer support the sqlplus commands ,as toad also support that F5 is the command in toad to run such commands.

Comment: to select from V$PARAMETER (synonym) you need grant on V_$PARAMETER (view)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Overview of the services used by all sessions  provides the distionary view `v$session`(or `gv$session` for RAC databases) in the column `SERVICE_NAME`.

To limit the information to the connected session use the SID from the view `V$MYSTAT`:

```
select SERVICE_NAME from gv$session where sid in (
select sid from V$MYSTAT)
```

If the name is [`SYS$USERS`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/create.htm#ADMIN13994) the session is connected to a *default* service, i.e. in the connection string no explicit service_name was specified.

To see what services are *available* in the database use following queries:

```
select name from V$SERVICES;
select name from V$ACTIVE_SERVICES;
```

Comment: This just says `SYS$USERS` for me when I'm on the machine using SQL*Plus directly.

Comment: @jpmc26 [SYS$USERS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/create.htm#sthref468) is the default service for user sessions that are not associated with services

Comment: I gathered, but the fact it doesn't work when running on the same machine makes this answer much less useful than others.

Comment: @jpmc26 extended the answer thaks to your suggestion. It is important to distinct the *connected* service and the *available* services.

Answer (score 87):

Found here, no DBA : [Checking oracle sid and database name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288122/checking-oracle-sid-and-database-name)

```
select * from global_name;
```

Comment: Many thanks, this one worked for me from Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: [GLOBAL_NAME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_5102.htm#REFRN29019) gets you the global database name, which is not the same as the Service Name. (Although in some instances they could happen to be have the same value.)

Answer (score 51):

Connect to the server as "system" using SID. 
Execute this query:

```
select value from v$parameter where name like '%service_name%';
```

It worked for me.

Comment: for anyone who need some help please note that the url needs the sid and not the service name. The full service name didn't work for me: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl.athens.intrasoft-intl.private` while this worked: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl`

Comment: @GeorgePligor:  Please note the difference: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:SID` but `jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT/SERVICE`  Replace the uppercase words by the correct values. Please note the difference between the two strings: in the sid string the name of the sid ist separated by a : from the preceding string, in the service string the name is separated by a / from the preceding string

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to this thread (https://community.oracle.com/thread/473276)

`select sys_context('userenv','service_name') from dual;`

It can be executed with a regular user account, no need for sysdba rights

Comment: All it returns is SYS$USERS. I did eventually get in contact with the DBA, so this is no longer an issue

Comment: This actually did return the current Service_name as defined in the TNSNames for me. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 13):

Check the service name of a database by

sql> show parameter service;

Comment: `SHOW PARAMETERS;` for everything.

Answer (score 4):

Connect to the database with the "system" user, and execute the following command:

```
show parameter service_name
```

Answer (score -1):

TO FIND ORACLE_SID USE $. oraenv

Answer (score -5):

With SQL Developer you should also find it without writing any query.
Right click on your Connection/Propriety.

You should see the name on the left under something like "connection details" and should look like "Connectionname@servicename", or on the right, under the connection's details.