# How to get database name in oracle db in node js without query using connection object

Tags: node.js, oracle, database-connection, node-oracledb

### How to get database name in oracle db node js

---

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
oracledb.getConnection(
    {
        user: 'c##root',
        password: 'root',
        connectString: 'localhost:1521/orcl'
    },
    function (err, connection) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('error while connect to OracleDB :' + err.stack);
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Database connected")
            connection.execute("INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES  ( :NAME) ", ['DOE'], function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                } else {
                    console.log("Value sucessfully added to database: " + "'database name here'")
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

---

I want to get name of the database when each time execute particular query.

Comment: What name are you referring to?  Do you want `orcl` to be returned in this case (assuming that is the database SID)?  Or do you want the schema name `c##root`?  Or something else?  Why don't you want to use the connection object?

Comment: yes i want to get SID (orcl) using connection object.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to find Oracle Service Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399766/how-to-find-oracle-service-name)

`select sys_context('userenv','service_name') from dual;`

PS in the given code, `orcl` is a service name, not a SID.