# C# Console application - connection to Oracle 12c

Tags: c#, connection, oracle12c

I am using **VS 2015** and I would like to make a connect on **Oracle 12c DB instaled on docker**.
I have already created all credentials necessary for succefull login (it was tested by SQLDeveloper).

Now I need in C# make a succesfull

- Open ()
- Disconnect()
- Query process (Select)
- Inserty/Update/Delete  - process

Do you have some ide for working example? Because this is not working:
*this is my code for DB:*

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

namespace namespace_name_x
{
    class OraConnect
    {
        public OracleConnection con;
        public void Connect()
        {
            con = new OracleConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;Data Source=localhost:1521/ORCLCDB.localdomain;Pooling = false;";
            con.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" + con.ServerVersion);
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my code in main

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
namespace namespace_name_x
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create a connection to Oracle
            OraConnect ot = new OraConnect();
            ot.Connect();
            string cmdstr = "SELECT NAME FROM ANY_TABLE";            

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdstr, ot);
            OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Employee Name: " + reader.GetString(0));
            }
etc...
```

and it is not working. It is only SELECT query.
Do you have any idea?
thank you

*PS: advices from this link are not working!* ([How to connect Oracle 12c data base through console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998687/how-to-connect-oracle-12c-data-base-through-console-application))

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?  Can you tell us exactly the error you receive and where.

Comment: in line  
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdstr, ot); should be error:

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'namespace_name_x.OraConnect' to 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection'