# node-oracledb TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I recently moved from on prem DBs where I used `Oracle 11g` to Cloud where I needed to connect to `Oracle 12c`. My `nodejs` app worked okay on prem but in the cloud, threw the error below

```
error: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Below is the code snippet that my app was using.

```
oracledb.createPool({
    user: config.DB_USER,
    password: config.DB_PASS,
    connectString: config.DB_HOST + ':' +
    config.DB_PORT + '/' +
    config.DB_NAME,
    poolMin: 20,
    poolIncrement: 0,    
    poolMax: 20
}
```

After searching around and trying multiple options including swapping `:` with `/` nothing seemed to work. I finally managed to get a working solution and I have answered this question below. I hope it helps someone

Answer (score 3):

For whoever is receiving this error while using oracledb package in NodeJS, this is how I fix the issue.

Before, I used this code below, which was producing this error:

`ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`

```
 //Old Code Which was producing the error
 connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
        user: "YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE",
        password: "YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE",
        connectString: "YOUR_DB_IP_HERE:YOUR_DB_PORT_HERE/YOUR_SERVICE_NAME_HERE"
 });
```

Then, after that, I found out that we need to change the value of connectString to give more details. Use the below code:

```
 //NEW Code After fixing
 connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
        user: "YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE",
        password: "YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE",
        connectString:"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=YOUR_DB_IP_HERE"+")(Port=YOUR_DB_PORT_HERE"+"))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=YOUR_SERVICE_NAME_HERE"+")))",
 });
```

And then the issue got fixed!.

Comment: Your problem was that you are actually using a SID not a 'service name', as you can see by the use of the keyword 'SID' (instead of the keyword 'SERVICE_NAME') in your second example.  The 'easy connect'  syntax in the first example only supports 'service names', not SIDs.  We encourage using service names because they offer more features.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was changing the connection string as shown in the code snippet below

```
oracledb.createPool({
    user: config.DB_USER,
    password: config.DB_PASS,
    connectString:"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host="+config.DB_HOST+")(Port="+config.DB_PORT+"))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID="+config.DB_NAME+")))",
    poolMin: 20,
    poolIncrement: 0,    
    poolMax: 20
},
```

Comment: As you found, the Easy Connect syntax supports Oracle Database service names, not the older System Identifiers (SID). https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-1421-easy-connect-syntax-for-connection-strings See the following about getting the service name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399766/how-to-find-oracle-service-name

Comment: You should explore why you can't use a service name.  Services are the new way of connecting (well - they have been around for many many releases) and they are used to provide failover, Application Continuity and other high availability features.  All the autonomous cloud db's provide service names for connection.