# ORA-01017: nom utilisateur/mot de passe non valide ; connexion refusée. when trying to connect to Oracle 19c

Tags: sqlplus, oracle19c

My university has sent us a pdf with instructions on how to connect to the Oracle server via DataGrip to work from home because the platform that we've been using so far isn't that great and allows only to see the results of queries. The tl;dr is:

1. Connect to the university network either via ethernet either via their VPN
2. Create a certain configuration on Datagrip and in the User and Password fields, fill them with our university login details.

The problem is that several of us have tried this configuration but no one succeeded. We all get the error "ORA-01017: nom utilisateur/mot de passe non valide ; connexion refusée.". I'm certain that the password I put is correct and that I'm correctly connected to the university network. I've read other responses here that say it has to do with the drivers and the case sensitivity of the password. I tried changing the drivers Datagrip uses: from the latest version to 11.2.0.4 to 19.3.0.0 but nothing happened. I even tried  specifying manually the DBMS Oracle version near the Test Connection button but it still won't work. I even tried connecting with Oracle SQL Developper but I still get the same error. We sent an email to the IT department of the university but it's been a week and no one has responded yet. If anyone has any idea on what is happening here and what can I do to successfully connect, I'll be grateful.

For reference, I tried finding out the version the server uses. I connected to the other platform that only allows us to see the results of queries and executed

```sql
SELECT banner FROM v$version WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

and got the following result

````
SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Oct 10 14:22:20 2023                                                               
Version 21.8.0.0.0                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                    
Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.                                                                             
                                                                                                                                    
Heure de la derniere connexion reussie : Mar. Oct.  10 2023 14:22:09 +00:00                                                         
                                                                                                                                    
Connecte a :                                                                                                                        
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production                                                              
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Session modifiee.                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                    
BANNER                                                                                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                    
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production```
````

Comment: Useful tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14476875/14357

Comment: Are you sure the connection and user details match the working client/tool? Particularly the service name you're connecting to; possibly the config they sent is what they use to connect to the CDB rather than a PDB? Maybe [check your service name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51193831/266304) when connected in the other tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out that the password was wrong but not because I typed it wrong...

The university forgot to tell us that while our university username was correct, we shouldn't use our password because they had created seperate passwords for the Oracle database and pushed them inside each student's HOME directory. So essentially we had the password all along but weren't aware of it.

Comment: This solution is unlikely to be of help to any future readers. The question has now been closed, so it may be best to delete this answer or make it a comment on the question, instead.