# Which DB am i connected to currently?

Tags: oracle

I am working in a project which has huge amounts of DATA, hence we are using two DBs. Now my question is, how will i know to which DB my system is currently connected to?

Comment: You mean which instance? Or tablespace?

Comment: If usernames are diffferent then  you can use
`select user from dual;`

Comment: Hi Patrick, I am looking for the instance.

Comment: "hence we are using two DBs" - bad idea detected

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking oracle sid and database name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288122/checking-oracle-sid-and-database-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the variable `instance_name` from the context:

```
select sys_context
       ( 'userenv'
       , 'instance_name'
       )
from   dual
```