# SQLPLUS error:ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I downloaded SQLPLUS from Oracle:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

Basic Lite and SQL*Plus

I then fired up SQL*Plus:

```
c:\Program Files\Oracle\instantclient_12_1>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Apr 15 15:25:36 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
```

and tried to connect to a database:

```
connect user\password@hostname
```

and received the error message:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
```

What am I missing?

I ran the queries suggested by Jakub,  I got

```
SQL> select sys_context('USERENV','SERVICE_NAME') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SERVICE_NAME')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SYS$USERS

SQL> select sys_context('USERENV','SID') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

877

SQL>
```

Comment: Do u have the tns entries entered in the tnsnames.Ora file ?

Comment: I do not have a tsnames.ora file.  I am attempting to connect using an ip address (should have mentioned that, sorry!)

Comment: Is the database residing in your machine (windows) or on a server ? (probably linux , aix ....)?

Comment: Not on my machine.  Not sure what the server is running.

Answer (score 32):

You're missing service name:

```
 SQL> connect username/password@hostname:port/SERVICENAME
```

**EDIT**

If you can connect to the database from other computer try running there:

```
select sys_context('USERENV','SERVICE_NAME') from dual
```

and

```
select sys_context('USERENV','SID') from dual
```

Comment: OK! Now, how do I discover the servicename for an oracle server at a given ip address?

Comment: Check listener.ora file on the database server. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/listener.htm#NETRF008

Comment: I don't have permission to login to the server, just a userid that can read some tables I need.  However, I do have access to a server that CAN login using an alias. so connect user\pass@alias works OK.  I guess there's no way to discover the servicename from an open connection, though.  Now I'm wondering if it is enough to copy the tsnames.ora, listener.ora. sqlnet.ora files to my pc.  If I did that, where would I put them?

Comment: I copied the tsnames.ora, sqlnet.or and listener.ora from a box where sqlplus works to my own machine. however, when I try to connect, I get: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: Open tnsnames.ora (it is text file) and check CONNECT_DATA there should be SERVICE_NAME or SID. Then try to connect to the database with full connection url.

Comment: The entry in tsnames.ora that I want is `SAUAPRD = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = nn.nn.nn.nn)(PORT = mmmm)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SID = SAUAPRD) ) )` I tried to connect using `connect xxxx/xxxxx@sauaprd`. It took a while but eventually produced the error `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

Comment: Try to run: sqlplus xxxx/xxxxx@nn.nn.nn.nn:mmmm/SAUAPRD

Comment: different error this time: `ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor`

Comment: I ran the queries you posted. I got ` SQL> select sys_context('USERENV','SERVICE_NAME') from dual; SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SERVICE_NAME') -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- SYS$USERS SQL> select sys_context('USERENV','SID') from dual; SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID') -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 877 SQL>`

Comment: Thanks. SERVICE_NAME helped, but SID didnt work for me.

Answer (score 23):

I ran into the exact same problem under identical circumstances. I don't have the tnsnames.ora file, and I wanted to use SQL*Plus with Easy Connection Identifier format in command line. I solved this problem as follows.

The [SQL*Plus® User's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_three.htm#SQPUG358) gives an example:

> sqlplus hr@\"sales-server:1521/sales.us.acme.com\"

Pay attention to two important points:

1. The connection identifier is quoted. You have two options:

   1. You can use SQL*Plus CONNECT command and simply pass quoted string.
   2. If you want to specify connection parameters on the command line then you must add backslashes as shields before quotes. It instructs the bash to pass quotes into SQL*Plus.
2. The service name must be specified in FQDN-form as it configured by your DBA.

I found these good questions to detect service name via existing connection: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399766/how-to-find-oracle-service-name), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288122/checking-oracle-sid-and-database-name). Try this query for example:

```
SELECT value FROM V$SYSTEM_PARAMETER WHERE UPPER(name) = 'SERVICE_NAMES'
```

Comment: There are no quotes shown for the connect identifier when running `sqlplus --help`... Thank you so much!

Comment: This also worked for me! Thanks! I used this in bash:
```sqlplus 'system@"//localhost:1521/xe"'```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small observation: you keep mentioning conn usr\pass, and this is a typo, right? Cos it should be conn usr/pass. Or is it different on a Unix based OS?

Furthermore, just to be sure: if you use tnsnames, your login string will look different from when you use the login method you started this topic out with.

tnsnames.ora should be in $ORACLE_HOME$\network\admin. That is the Oracle home on the machine from which you are trying to connect, so in your case your PC. If you have multiple oracle_homes and wish to use only one tnsnames.ora, you can set environment variable tns_admin (e.g. set TNS_ADMIN=c:\oracle\tns), and place tnsnames.ora in that directory.

Your original method of logging on (usr/pwd@10.15.240.13:port/servicename) should always work. So far I think you have all the info, except for the port number, which I am sure your DBA will be able to give you. If this method still doesn't work, either the server's IP address is not available from your client, or it is a firewall issue (blocking a certain port), or something else not (directly) related to Oracle or SQL*Plus.

hth!
Regards,
Remco

Comment: I don't have oracle installed on my machine.  I only have the sqlplus executable.  Nothing else.  OTOH I do believe that a firewall may be in the way.

Answer (score 0):

I faced such strange behavior only in one server and only from script
it worked when I put env variable TNS_ADMIN
despite it was default location network/admin

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin/impdp username/password@aws-rds-hostname:1521/DATABASENAME DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=filename.dmp logfile=filename.log full=y